# What is the double integral of the infinitesimal of a function: $dE(x_i,y_i)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm confused about the math in my textbook. It gives a formula $dE(x_i,y_i)=f(x_i,y_i,x_0,y_0)dx_0dy_0$ (where I give f(...) for simplicity sake) and then jumps to $E(x_i,y_i)=K*\int \int f(x_i,y_i,x_0,y_0)dx_0dy_0$

So is it always true that a double integral of an infinitesimal of a function yields the function itself? I've never seen this before, and also why does this yield a constant K?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is true, integrating the differential of a function yields that function itself

For instance,

$\int$$dx = x + C$

$\int d(\frac{e^{x^2}}{t}) = \frac{e^{x^2}}{t} + C$

$\iint$$dA = A$

$\iiint$$dV = V$

Which becomes particularly useful in solving differential equations

In this case, $E = E(x_i,y_i)$ and the equation is written in differential form since $f$ is squashed by $dx_0dy_0$, which represents an infinitesimal patch of area. So integrating twice recovers $E(x_i,y_i)$

$\iint$$dE(x_i,y_i) = E(x_i,y_i) + C$

Where C (also seen commonly as K) is a constant that depends on the system.

But I'm not sure where K comes from in what you described since it's attached to $\iint$$fdx_0dy_0$ through multiplication.

Given a number b, it's certainly true that

$b + C \equiv kb$

for some numbers C and k, but this is not true with functions, $b = b(x)$, unless $C = 0$ and $k = 1$

Maybe it's a typo